# Barchart "dates" are displaying strange / bars are pressed

Tags: d3.js, bar-chart

I want to create a barchart displaying C02 emission.

The Problem (see picture below):

**Why are the bars "pushed" to the right? Why are the years in the x-axis displayed without the first integer?**

I am using Version 3 of d3.

Given some JSON data like this:

```
     [
      {
        "Cement": 0.0,
        "Gas Flaring": 0.0,
        "Gas Fuel": 0.0,
        "Liquid Fuel": 0.0,
        "Per Capita": null,
        "Solid Fuel": 3.0,
        "Total": 3.0,
        "Year": 1751
      }, 
and so on…
]
```

To prepare for scaling I did:

```
  var minDate = dataset[0].Year;
  var maxDate = dataset[dataset.length - 1].Year;

 var maxValue = d3.max(dataset, function(d) {
    return d["Per Capita"];
  });
```

I append the svg

```
var svg = d3
    .select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);
```

I sacled the xAxis and the yAxis:

```
  var xAxisScale = d3.time
    .scale()
    .domain([minDate, maxDate])
    .range([0, w]);

  var yAxisScale = d3.scale
    .linear()
    .domain([0, maxValue])
    .range([h, 0]);
```

The I finally builded these axisses…

```
 var xAxis = d3.svg
    .axis()
    .scale(xAxisScale)
    .orient("bottom");

  var yAxis = d3.svg
    .axis()
    .scale(yAxisScale)
    .orient("left");

  svg
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(92," + (h - padding) + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

  svg
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + padding + ",-90)")
    .call(yAxis);
```

I also than addeded the rects…

```
  svg
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .style("fill", "teal")
    .attr({
      x: function(d, i) {
        return i * (w / dataset.length);
      },
      y: function(d) {
        return yAxisScale(d["Per Capita"]);
      },
      width: w / dataset.length,
      height: function(d) {
        return h - yAxisScale(d["Per Capita"]);
      }
    });
```

The result is not the intended one.
[image: The bars are "pressed" to the right. The x-sclales Years have these floating point instead of the Millenia]

Could you please elaborate what went wrong?

**Why are the bars "pushed" to the right?
Why are the years in the x-axis displayed without the first integer?**

I am using Version 3 of d3.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The main problem here is that this...

```
"Year": 1751
```

... is not a date object. That's just a number. If you look at your axis you'll realise that.

So, you have to parse it. For instance:

```
const format = d3.time.format("%Y");
dataset.forEach(function(d){
    d.Year = format.parse(d.Year);
});
```

Also, when you do this...

```
var minDate = dataset[0].Year;
var maxDate = dataset[dataset.length - 1].Year;
```

... you're blindly trusting that the array is sorted. Don't do that. Instead, do:

```
var minDate = d3.max(dataset, function(d){
    return d.Year
});
var maxDate = d3.min(dataset, function(d){
    return d.Year
});
```

Or, if you want to use destructuring:

```
var [minDate, maxDate] = d3.extent(dataset, d => d.Year);
```

Finally, now that you have a proper scale, don't use the indices for the `x` position. Use the scale:

```
x: function(d) {
    return xAxisScale(d.Year);
},
```

This covers the problem regarding the `x` position. For fixing the `y` position, just set a proper margin.

Comment: Hi Gerardo, many thanks for your answer. But when I do, as you said, console throw an error "d3.timeParse is not a function".  I tried it also just with "time". Like: `d3.time("%Y")` it does not work either.

Comment: @S.H That's my bad, you're using v3. please check the answer again.